# Electron application in production throw: error Command failed: node index.js but in development works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

Have you ever had this issue:

I was working on my app in development, and everything works fine, but when I created the executable and try to click on my button throw this error:

This the code that is executed when I press my button:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
let myBtn = document.getElementById('my-btn');



myBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  exec("node index.js", (error, data, getter) => {
    if(error){
      console.log("error",error.message);
      return;
    }
    if(getter){
      console.log("data",data);
      return;
    }
    console.log("data",data);
  
  });
    
});
```

This the error:
Not recognize the module `node` and my file `index.js`

```
error Command failed: node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/myUser/index.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1065:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:911:27)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "^12.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with electron-forge, but I suspect that **index.js** isn't getting copied or the path that `exec("node index.js" ...` is being called from; it can't find **index.js**.

Comment: Think you have to use path, in order for .exec to execute the command in the write place.